# Temperature of 100w bulb

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, temperature, thermal-radiation, power

What is the running temperature of a 100w bulb if it's resistance while on is 50 ohms and the mains voltage is 240 V RMS.

Comment: Do you mean the temperature of the incandescent filament, or the temperature of the outer surface of the bulb?

Comment: The incandescent filament

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient research effort. An answer is easily found in the featured hit found by googling the question title : https://www.pacificlamp.com/temperature-of-a-100-watt-bulb.asp

Comment: This is a duplicate, but also *you can't compute the temperature from that information*: you *can* compute the power output, but that is not enough to know the temperature.

Comment: It is about the same as that of a 6 volt 0.05 amps bicycle light.

Comment: @sammygerbil, that link doesn't answer the question.   That is to say, it gives a _typical_ answer, but not a _physics_ answer.  An incandescent light bulb basically is a resistor.  You can not predict the temperature of a resistor knowing only how much power it dissipates.  It could be hot enough to give you a sunburn (e.g., a tiny tungsten halogen projector lamp), or it could be cool enough that it gives off no visible light at all (e.g., a big old ceramic power resistor.)

Comment: @jameslarge Yes  you are quite right. My first impression was that the question is asking for factual information, rather than a method of calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old black body experiment. Typically you would use the Stefan–Boltzmann law ( P proportional to T^4), but keep in mind the filament is not a perfect black body so a correction factor will be need to get your answer. Since you know the power from V^2/R.